# Rails form to create multiple associated objects for a parent object

Tags: ruby, forms, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to create a form in my Rails application that will allow me to create multiple associated objects with the main object I'm creating. My models are listed below:

```
class Bucket < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :resources
  belongs_to :user
end

class Resource < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :model
  has_attached_file :artifact
end
```

I want the ability to create multiple Resource objects while creating a Bucket object. So, when I go to create a new Bucket, I want to also be able to create multiple Resource objects on the same form.

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

```
class Bucket < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :resources  
  belongs_to :user  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :resources
end

class Resource < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :model  
  has_attached_file :artifact  
end
```

and then you can create your bucket either by sending a post request in this format.

```
bucket: {
  resources_attributes: [
    // resource objects go here
  ]  
}
```

or by using `fields_for` if you're using rails for the front-end part

```
<%= form_for @bucket do |bucket_form| %>  
  //  bucket form fields go here

  <%= bucket_form.fields_for :resources do |resource_fields| %>  
    // resource fields go here
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```

And you can check the documentation for more options for [`fields_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).

Comment: Thank you for the help! That solution makes perfect sense.